# how to update rows with same id and also with conditions?

Tags: mysql

I have a big table (addon_values_storage) where some additional product description is stored.

The column container_id represents the product id. Each product can have multiple entries in this table (addon_values_storage). All rows with the same container_id (which is unique) represent the additional description of one product.

No my problem:
I want to update some description with conditions. 
- only update within same container_id
- only update when some information exists within this container_id range

I tried something like this but i think this is not right:

```sql
UPDATE addon_values_storage
       SET addon_value = "TEXT"
       WHERE addon_key = "products_pc_tower_detail"
             AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM addon_values_storage
                                WHERE addon_values_storage.container_id = addon_values_storage.container_id
                                      AND addon_values_storage.addon_key = 'products_pc_groupid'
                                      AND addon_values_storage.addon_value = 'CL-AM4-iGPU');
```

This is how the table looks like:

[image: table]

(picute shows only some rows of container_id = 8, but there are many more 1-1100 container_id's each unique id has about 50 rows...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this achieve what you want?

(it should update `addon_values` for all entries having "products_pc_tower_detail" as `addon_key` **only if** there is another entry in the table with the same `container_id` and with `addon_key = 'products_pc_groupid'` and `addon_value = 'CL-AM4-iGPU'`)

```
UPDATE addon_values_storage avs1
JOIN addon_values_storage avs2
   ON avs1.container_id = avs2.container_id
   AND avs2.addon_key = 'products_pc_groupid'
   AND avs2.addon_value = 'CL-AM4-iGPU'
SET avs1.addon_value = "TEXT"
WHERE avs1.addon_key = "products_pc_tower_detail"
```

**Edit:** fixed the typo :)

Comment: works! only little type addons_values_storage -> addon_values_storage

Answer (score 0):

With a self join and the conditions in the `WHERE` clause:

```
update addon_values_storage t1
inner join addons_values_storage t2 on t1.container_id = t2.container_id
set t1.addon_value = "TEXT"
where 
      t1.addon_key = "products_pc_tower_detail"
  and t2.addon_key = 'products_pc_groupid'
  and t2.addon_value = 'CL-AM4-iGPU'
```